# Pyspark - Create Dataframe Copy Inside Loop And Update On Iteration

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to set the value of a list of columns (`columns`),to the value of another column (`share`), of a dataframe.
For this I wrote the following piece of code that does this:

```
for column in columns:
        df_return = df.withColumn(column, F.lit(df.share) )
```

This only updates the last column of the list. If instead of `df_return` is `df` the code works but I want to know:

- if it is possible to implement this without changing the initial dataframe?
- is there a simpler way/more efficient way of replicating one column's values to multiple others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select` statement with list comprehension.

```
keep_cols = ['share', 'some_col']
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df_return = df.select(*keep_cols, *[F.col('share').alias(x) for x in columns])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to create an empty dataframe and then name the dataFrame as the result

```
data = [()]
columns= []
df_rerun = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)

for column in columns:
        df = df.withColumn(column, F.lit(df.share) )
```

If you want to keep the original df as it is:

Quick example in Databricks here

[image]

Comment: I do not want to change the original dataframe. If I use `df_return=df_return.withColumn(column, F.lit(df.share))` I get the following error `local variable 'df_return' referenced before assignment`. I want to create a new dataframe inside the loop, before the loop, `df_return` does not exist.

Comment: oh i see, there is no initial dataframe, there you can create an empty Dataframe and then do that. I'll update my answer